# iOs game - lives refill

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, timer

I'm working on match 3 game in there I need to add lives. If user didn't solve puzzle he loses 1 life. I made it but how I can make lives refill every 20 minutes? I'm stuck. Another on problem is if game moves to background, how to check after user open game again?

My game is `Sprite Kit` project on `objective-c`

Comment: 1.add desired number to lives variable after 20 minutes.
2.Application did enter foreground.

Answer (score 0):

**First part of your question:**

You are looking for some timer. You could use `NSTimer` to call a method every 20m or `SKAction` with `waitForDuration` method init.

**Second part of your question:**

In your `AppDelegate` find or add method `applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application`
. This method is called everytime your app should become active. Or `addObserver` for `applicationWillEnterForeground` notification where you need it.